# How do I specify a custom POST action when using `match` in my `routes.rb` file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, controller, action

I'm trying to define a custom `post` action in a controller, but I'm having some questions.

This is my controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ExamplesController < ApplicationController
      def create_a
        ...
      end

      def create_b
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I want both actions/methods to be `post` actions. This is what I have in my routes file:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    match 'examples/create_a', :controller => 'examples', :action => 'create_a'
    match 'examples/create_b', :controller => 'examples', :action => 'create_b'
  end
end
```

I can reach these two methods via `ge`t requests, but I'd like to trigger them based on an http `post`. Also, if I check via `rake routes` it does not tell me if it's a GET, PUT, POST, etc. method. It's just blank. How do I tell a route that it's supposed to be a `post` method?

And how would a `post` request in the browser look like to my method?

```
url: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/examples/create_a.json/create_a
header: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
data: paramA=45&paramB&paramC
```

Is this the proper URL pattern to do a `post` to my controller action `create_a`?

Comment: try "post" instead of "match'. "match" defaults to get action.

Comment: "match" should route any kind of request, at least it does for me.

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edits. I cleaned up some minor formatting things, and rephrased the title to be both (a) more specific to your question, and (b) form it into a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you use `match` when you want to map some kind of logical name to a RESTful route and/or to create an alias for a RESTful route. What you're doing with `match` is fine (in the sense that it will work), but you're just missing a small thing (which I'll so you later).

First, let's look at a typical use for `match` creating an alias for a route:

```
match "profile" => "users#show"
```

This route lets you use an application path of `/profile` to `show` a `user` instead of the path `/users/:id`.

Since your code isn't mapping one name to another, you don't need a `match` rule. Your use of `match` adds duplication to your code that isn't necessary, and using `match` in the case you presented is more verbose than necessary. Here's an example of how you could write your API routes **without** `match`, specifying that they are accessible via `post` only:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    post "examples/create_a"
    post "examples/create_b"
  end
end
```

And here's an example **with** `match`, adding the `:via` parameter (which is what you're missing in your code example) to specify the HTTP verb:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    match 'examples/create_a' => "examples#create_a", :via => :post
    match 'examples/create_b' => "examples#create_b", :via => :post
  end  #           ^ ---- DUPLICATION ---- ^
end
```

Note the duplication of code here. Since you're not mapping one path name to another you've typed your **identically named paths twice** when compared to the **non-**`match` version.

You'll also note that I took out the `:controller` and `action` parameters when compared to your original example code, as Rails will infer this automatically when you use the form:

```
"[controller]/[action]" => "[controller]#[action]"
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! So my post url would look like this: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/examples#create_a" ?

Comment: Close. It would be `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/examples/create_a` (note the slash between the controller and action name). The `#` is just the convention in the routes. In your case I would use the first example (**without** the use of `match`), because as you can see, the second example specifies the route twice. Since you're not remapping one route name to another, you don't need `match`, and as such, you can avoid this duplication.

Comment: I've updated my answer to better highlight the unnecessary duplication of code in the `match` example.

Answer (score 2):

Adding :via => :post should do the trick.

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    match 'examples/create_a', :controller => 'examples', :action => 'create_a', :via => :post
    match 'examples/create_b', :controller => 'examples', :action => 'create_b', :via => :post
  end
end
```

More information is available at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I think you misunderstood a little the job of `match` method. It will allow ANY http verb to be used with the specified path. By using `:via` you just put some constraints on it, limiting its acceptance to the verb(s) you specified.